# Is JQuery still supported for couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

Where can I find the JQuery plugin / library for couchdb? I installed couchdb on windows and while the localhost:5984 "Fauxton" url works, many other `_utils` urls including the jquery urls I found on stackoverflow and other places on the internet (e.g. `http://localhost:5984/_utils/script/couch.js`) will give a not found error on localhost:5984

Comment: Do you mean you want to connect to couchdb from jQuery?  Or you want to use jQuery from within map/reduce functions? Or something else?

Comment: yes connect, I've been using the library I posted in the comment of the answer. Seems to work so far. I had no luck finding it in the v2.0,0.1 couchdb I downloaded even though information around the internet suggests it should be at the urls above

Answer (score 0):

The URL I use (admittedly not on Windows) is different to the one you are trying. Could you try this instead?

```
/_utils/script/jquery.js
```

and the couch library itself...

```
/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js
```

Comment: yes, both "not found." responses... e.g. 'http://localhost:5984/_utils/script/jquery.js' . Hower I've since discovered, [apache/couchdb-jquery-couch: Mirror of Apache CouchDB](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-jquery-couch) . I think this is the same thing? I mean the few functins that I tried work as in the documentation I could find on the internet, I'm just wondering if it is completely up to date.